# Вопрос по регулярным выражениям Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Почему при такой регулярке:

`r'<a href="(.*)">'`

он вытаскивает:

> https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample1.html

А не `<a href=https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample1.html">`? С данным вопросом столкнулся в задаче https://stepik.org/lesson/24471/step/6?thread=solutions&unit=6780. Я использовал такое регулярное: `r'http.*html'`, но среди решений нашел то, что указал выше. Не понял, почему оно работает именно так:)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161219/398802

Comment: Приведите код, который так "вытаскивает"

Comment: Так вы же указали группу в круглых скобках. Ее и возвращает.

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете найти подстроку(-и):

```py
import re
print(*re.findall(regex, text))
```

Можете найти соответствующую строку (или соответствует ли строка):

```py
import re
out = re.search(regex, text)
if out:
    print(out.group(0))
```

По-моему все просто ;)

## Как это работает с вашим примером

```
text = '<a href="https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample1.html">'
regex = r'<a href="(.*)">'
```

**in**:

```
import re
print(*re.findall(regex, text))
```

***stdout***:

```
https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample1.html
```

---

**in**:

```
import re
out = re.search(regex, text)
if out:
    print(out.group(0))
```

***stdout***:

```
<a href="https://stepic.org/media/attachments/lesson/24472/sample1.html">
```